# Adding email to publish_stream scope to facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Facebook application that posts regularly, every day, one article to the joined users time line. Currently, I use the following getLoginUrl code with *publish_stream* scope:

```
$facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream'));
```

Since, my website is currently working and it has users joined its application. I don't want to make any adventure that may stop posting articles to users.

My question is: will adding email to the scope string cause to stop posting articles to users till they login next time using Facebook login URL? Or just posting articles will be continued as usual and just my app will not be able to know the email till the user login again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app will continue to work the same way, the only difference is when you do this

```
$this->facebook->api('/me','GET');
```

If the user hasn't granted the email permission will get this

```
id
name
first_name
last_name
link
username
gender
locale
age_range
```

If the user has granted the email permission, then you''l just have one more field with email of the user:

```
id
name
first_name
last_name
link
username
gender
locale
age_range
email
```

So don't worry you cand add that scope as long as you verify if the array email key exists

Comment: No, there will be no such error – you will just not get the `email` property in the API response, even when explicitly requested.

Comment: you're right, you just need to verify if $facebook->api('/me','GET'); returns the email field